# Commitment devices to remedy investment mistakes?

Tags: portfolio-management, trading, behavioral-finance

I'm looking into a new question that came up lately.

Some of our clients here are prone to sell their gains too quickly while amassing larger positions of assets that have lost in value. Although this behavior is not visible all the time, we observed this habit already for some time, especially whenever markets are volatile and/or stock indices are falling and there is a downturn in the markets.

We were brainstorming yesterday, what kind of commitment devices of any kind we could offer them as we noted during our discussions with them that their original plans were to hold those positions if they made a gain and sell at a certain level once they lose value. These comments made it clear that there seems to be some sort of time-inconsistent strategic planning going on here.

My boss suggested to use call options as commitment device, others have suggested to use dynamic stop-loss rules, which i see critical as the clients might not accept them if they are too restrictive. Others have suggested structured products with an increasing upside participation and a narrow barrier below the strike.  We checked and the losses among those who show this disposition are quite considerable so there is a need for these.

My question is: Do you have some ideas what rules or devices or instruments can be used and how they could work to remedy this or other behavioral biases? We have a working behavioral model in place to check for the effects and i'd like to share the results with you here given your suggestions.

Thank you in advance,
Thomas